# Python - Add Two arrays with same string and numbers

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to add two arrays with string and numbers together. and I am getting

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

```
array_a = np.array(['A', 2, 6, 5, 8, 9, 3, 6, 6, 0, 1])
array_b = np.array(['A', 5, 7, 1, 8, 9, 4, 6, 0, 5, 1])
array_c = array_a + array_b
```

I am expecting the output to be

```
array_c = ['A', 7, 13, 6, 16, 18, 7, 12, 6, 5, 2]
```

Comment: Why is there an 'A' in both arrays? You can't expect that NumPy knows that 'A' + 'A' should result in 'A' again.

Comment: It seems like the 'A' has no real meaning and you should just be adding the arrays without the 'A': `array_a[1:] + array_b[1:]`, or not include the 'A' in the arrays at all.

Comment: Have you checked the output of `np.array(['A', 2, 6, 5, 8, 9, 3, 6, 6, 0, 1])`? You won't have mixed strings and numbers, everything is string. What you want to do makes no sense in numpy. You probably should use pandas or python lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
array_a = np.array(['A', 2, 6, 5, 8, 9, 3, 6, 6, 0, 1])
array_b = np.array(['A', 5, 7, 1, 8, 9, 4, 6, 0, 5, 1])
array_c =  [int(array_a[i])+int(array_b[i]) if array_a[i].isdigit() else array_a[i] for i in range(len(array_a)) ]
print(array_c)

#output: ['A', 7, 13, 6, 16, 18, 7, 12, 6, 5, 2]
```

Comment: I corrected immediately as I mistakenly read the output

Comment: Please see now.

Comment: Thank you! This is working as I expected to be

Comment: with your correction, works fine!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help you:

```
import numpy as np

def sum_arrays_mixed_types(array_a, array_b):
  result = []
  
  result = [int(a) + int(b) if str(a).isdigit() and str(b).isdigit() else a for a, b in zip(array_a, array_b)]
  return result

array_a = np.array(['A', 2, 6, 5, 8, 9, 3, 6, 6, 0, 1])
array_b = np.array(['A', 5, 7, 1, 8, 9, 4, 6, 0, 5, 1])

sum_arrays_mixed_types(array_a, array_b)
```

I used `str(a).isdigit()` and `str(b).isdigit()` to know if the element is a digit or not. And the `zip()` function to iterate through `array_a` and `array_b` simultaneously.